# Optparse library - callback action while storing arg

Tags: python, ironpython, optparse

My code:

```
def main():
    usage = "usage: %prog [options] arg"
    parser = OptionParser(usage)
    parser.add_option("-p", "--pending", action="callback", callback=pending, type="string", dest="test", help="View Pending Jobs")
    (options, args) = parser.parse_args()
    if x == 0:
        print usage, " (-h or --help for help)"
    print options.test
```

if i had:
*script* -p hello

i need options.test to print out the argument as type string

Comment: If your using optparse it will generate the help info for you automatically.  use "parser.print_help()".

Comment: I've been looking at that and the library documentation for over an hour now

Comment: Why in the world are you using a 'callback' option? Remove the 'action=" and 'callback=' and even 'type=' parameters and it will do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arguments are available through *sys.argv*.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up passing the argument to the function that is being called.